Ionic angular adyen integration
we have a ionic v1 angular cordova app for android and we are trying to integrate adyen https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/build-your-integration/sessions-flow/?platform=Web&integration=Drop-in&version=5.60.0. However, I noticed they don't have a out of the box support for cordova or any plugin.
What i tried

I tried integrating the web sdk in the anroid mobile app, however it did not workout i noticed app freeze.
I tried devloping a cordova android plugin, the examples looks too complex and i have limited knowledge in kotlin

What i expected

I expected a payment form by adyen, or in case of android plugin i expected an activity with payment form

Please point me as to what approach i can take.

After viewing the docs, The ONLY way to use this would be creating a cordova or capacitor plugin that utilizes the SDK. Goodluck!
